# Trying to get a specific line from a file. Program skips lines. (PHP)

Tags: php, file-io

I have a small problem. I need to get a line from a text file using PHP. Here is an example of the text file:

hello 2010-10-25
hello 2010-10-26
hello 2010-10-27
hello 2010-10-28
hello 2010-10-29
hello 2010-10-30
hello 2010-10-31

And my code for taking out a the line which contains "2010-10-26" is this:

```
<?php
 $datefile = fopen('file.txt', 'r') or exit("Unable to open file.txt");

 while(!feof($datefile))
 {
  $date = "2010-10-26";
  $string = fgets($datefile);
  if(strpos($string, $date)==true)
  {
   echo fgets($datefile);
  }

 }
 fclose($datefile);
?>
```

Instead of printing out the line "hello 2010-10-26", it prints out "hello 2010-10-27" I have no idea whats going on, please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When finding the row, you read the next line and return it.

```
echo fgets($datefile);
```

Instead you want to return the current line

```
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well like kingCrunch said instead of using 
 `echo fgets($datefile);`


use

```
echo $string;
```

or if you still want to use what you have been using, then set the date variable to a day less than what you want to get.

Comment: Hmm that can work, but I need the correct date, so I have to use his method :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Its much more easier to use [`file()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to read a lines of a file into an array.

Example:

```
$date = '2010-10-26';
foreach (file('file.txt') as $line) {
    if ($line == $date) {
        echo 'Match: '.$line;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
$date = '2010-10-26';
$lines = file('file.txt');

if (in_array('hello '.$date, $lines)) {
    echo 'Match '.$date;
}
```

Comment: There is more in one line than just the given date. So you can not test against equality.

Comment: @KingCrunch you are right, I added a 'hello ' prefix. But its not very nice.